# Query to remove leading zeros from a string in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a query that will scan a collection and update any string that contains a leading zero, ultimately dropping that leading zero.

So if I have storeId '0123' it would perform an update and save it as '123'.

I did some searching and have been trying to do something with the UpdateMany command, but so far nothing  is working, this is not as simple as I thought it would be.

Comment: Why did the developer get lost in the database? Because they didn't have a query that was specific enough to find what they were looking for! But in all seriousness, it sounds like your query isn't quite doing what you want it to. Can you provide more information about the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: Did you try `$trim` or `$ltrim`?